# \LaTeX command does not work in times font

Tags: fonts, times

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{uhv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{utm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{ucr}

\begin{document}

\LaTeX

\end{document}
```

I get the following messages

```
name = utmr8r, rootname = utmr8r, pointsize = mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

Cannot find font utmr8r in map file(s).

kpathsea: Running mktexmf utmr8r.mf The command name is C:\texlive\2012\bin\win32\mktexmf Cannot find utmr8r.mf . I try ps2pk --> gsftopk --> ttf2pk --> hbf2gf. ps2pk cannot be used.
I try gsftopk. gsftopk.exe utmr8r 420 gsftopk cannot be used.
Next I try ttf2pk. ttf2pk.exe -q utmr8r 420 ttf2pk failed.
Finally I try hbf2gf. hbf2gf.exe -q -p utmr8r 420 All trials failed. 
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+420/600 --dpi 420 utmr8r
The command name is C:\texlive\2012\bin\win32\mktexpk kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Works for me using your MWE.  If I comment/uncomment your `\rmdefault` line, I get a different appearance.

Comment: Works fine in miktex but not in TexLive. Looks as if TeXLive doesn't enable the map-file. Try if it work if you run `updmap-sys --enable Map utm.map`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer looks like an answer to me:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works fine in MikTeX but not in TeXLive. Looks as if TeXLive doesn't enable the `map`-file. Try if it work if you run

```
  updmap-sys --enable Map utm.map
```